# Error en módulo para formulario de joomla

Tags: php, joomla3

Estoy trabajando con *Joomla* e instalé un módulo para formularios de contacto, cuando lo publico me aparecen estos errores:

> -Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/site/public_html/modules/mod_jmcontact/tmpl/default.php on line
>   11
>
> -Warning: require_once(/home/site/public_html/modules/mod_jmcontact/tmplDSelement/recaptchalib.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/baldosines/public_html/modules/mod_jmcontact/tmpl/default.php on
>   line 12
>
> -Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/site/public_html/modules/mod_jmcontact/tmplDSelement/recaptchalib.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/baldosines/public_html/modules/mod_jmcontact/tmpl/default.php on
>   line 12

Estas son las líneas 11 y 12 refenciadas en los errores

```
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'element/recaptchalib.php');
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer estás usando un módulo desactualizado, Joomla! modificó dichos parámetros hace ya algún tiempo:

1. JFactory debe llamarse sin referencia a partir de PHP 5.3, más información: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php .

   `$document = JFactory::getDocument();`
2. Joomla! removió la constante `DS` en su versión 3.x , en su lugar agregó `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.
   Más información aquí: https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2#General_changes

   ```
   require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'element/recaptchalib.php');
   ```